# Problem in creating X509Certificate2 Public Key

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa, x509certificate2

I have an existing asp.net application where I use X509Certificate2 private and public keys. I am migrating it to netcoreapp2.1 (MVC). I'm facing a problem in creating a public key with X509Certificate2. I have the below code

```
  public string CertificatePublicKeyEncrypt(string stringToEncrypt, string certficatePath)
    {
        byte[] bytesToEncrypt = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);

        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certficatePath);

        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = cert.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

        byte[] encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(bytesToEncrypt, false);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
    }
```

in asp.net application, cert.Handle value is "0x0792e4a0" and rsa is created successfully where the certificate location is determined using Server.MapPath function as shown:

```
   req.Sender = helper.CreateSenderObj(txt_sender_id.Text, txt_sender_name.Text, txt_efinance_password.Text, Server.MapPath("~/Certificates/InternetPaymentCrt.cer"));
```

[Handle Value in asp.net Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZCsa.png)
but in our MVC project cert.Handle value is"0x0000019d814fffa0" and then rsa is null where the certificate location is determined using Hosting.ContentRootPath function as shown :

```
 var path = $"{Hosting.ContentRootPath}\\Certificates\\InternetPaymentCrt.cer"; 
         req.Sender = helper.CreateSenderObj(VM.SenderId, VM.SenderName, VM.SenderPassword,path);
```

[Handle Value in MCV Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csR53.png)
and gives null exception error as follows
[System.NullReferenceException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne09v.png)

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Core applications, `X509Certificate2.PublicKey` and `X509Certificate2.PrivateKey` are literally obsolete. You have to use [X509Certificate2 extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=net-6.0#extension-methods) (corresponding method depending on key algorithm) to retrieve public and private keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Crypt32 , using this line  var rsa = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPublicKey(cert); generates the RSA public key for me.  But the cert. Handle value = "0x000001862360cbe0" which is still  different from that generated by the asp.net application (cert . Handle = "0x08167878"). This leads to give different generated password

Comment: The line you are referencing does not generate the key, the line extracts the key handle from input certificate. Handles are allocated dynamically, so they are almost always different.

Comment: as you notice that there is a difference in the number of bytes where cert. Handle value = "0x000001862360cbe0" has 18 byes for asp.net application but for application core has 10 bytes(cert . Handle = "0x08167878"). I'm asking about the number of generated bytes

Comment: The difference in handle size comes from process bitness. 32-bit process use 32-bit pointers and 64-bit process use 64-bit pointers. Handle size is completely irrelevant to your question, it is simply a pointer to a memory location, nothing more.